# Adding native swift code to NativeScript application

Tags: ios, swift, typescript, vue.js, nativescript

I'm trying to add native swift code to my NativeScript app. According to these [instructions](https://docs.nativescript.org/guides/ios-source-code) in the documentation I can just add a swift source file to `App_Resources/iOS/src/` and then use any publicly exposed classes directly in my TypeScript code.
Unfortunately this just doesn't work. I'll just get `Cannot find name 'TestClass'` and that's it.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Get a fresh NS project with ios `tns create my-app-name --template tns-template-blank-ts`

**Update**: I actually created the App with `vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template testapp`. That seems to have caused the problems.

2. Add a `TestClass.swift` to `App_Resources/iOS/src/`

```swift
import Foundation

public class TestClass: NSObject {
    @objc public func echo(param: String) -> String {
        return param
    }
}
```

3. Instantiate it in any TypeScript source file `let instance = new TestClass()`
4. Do `tns debug ios`
5. Compilation will fail with `Cannot find name 'TestClass'`

I have also tried generating TypeScript typings with `TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="$(pwd)/typings" tns build ios` or or just delcaring it as any with `declare let KeyCommander: any;` to eliminate the possibility that this is a TS related problem. The first approach doesn't generate any typings for my custom class so the TypeScript code will still not compile. The second approach let's the TS code compile but crashes on execution with `JS ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TestClass`.

I have also verified that the swift file is indeed getting compiled by inserting a syntax error which will crash the build process.

My NativeScript version is `6.4.0`.

What am I missing?

**Update**: I just realized I actually created the App with `vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template testapp`. I verified that as mentioned [Tyler Blake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60313110/10612606) in an app created with the tns cli the described process actually works. In an app I just freshly created with `vue init` it doesn't, the `objc!nsswiftsupport.d.ts` is not being generated.

The question now is: What's causing the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by inspecting the differences between the templates created with `tns-cli` and `vue init`. The difference is that the `vue init` template ships with an outdated version of the nativescript platform. You can just simply change

```
"tns-ios": {
  "version": "6.0.1"
}
```

to version `6.4.0` (which the version the `tns-cli` template comes with) and then the process will work as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I followed your steps and I was able to get the typings to generate in `objc!nsswiftsupport.d.ts`. After you generate typings do you have that file with these contents?

```
declare class TestClass extends NSObject {

    static alloc(): TestClass; // inherited from NSObject

    static new(): TestClass; // inherited from NSObject

    echoWithParam(param: string): string;
}
```

This shows that NS is able to pick up the Swift code.

All you need to do now is add `tns-platform-declarations` then in the `references.d.ts` file, add a line that points to the `objc!nsswiftsupport.d.ts` file. Then you'll get intellisense in your TS code.

Something like this:

`/// <reference path="./typings/objc!nsswiftsupport.d.ts" />`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for trying! You are indeed right, the process I described actually works. I just realized though that I created the app with `vue init` as described in the nativescript-vue documentation. In the boilerplate app created with `vue init` the `objc!nsswiftsupport.d.ts` is not being generated. I can't really tell what's making the difference. Can you?

Comment: Nevermind. The difference is the version of "tns-ios" the templates come with. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out!